# How do I execute Bash commands and collect the output from Java?

Tags: java, bash, process, command

How do I execute Bash commands and collect the output from Java?

Hi all, basically I am writing a basic console app, and would like to be able to run commands from it, such as sudo***, halt, ifconfig, etc.

Any insight?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [processBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) API for this purpose. See [this example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html).

Comment: don't forget to call processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true).  Or spin up another thread to drain stderr.

Comment: I don't see any mention of bash in the "example"

Comment: Link to example broken.

Comment: Do you have another example link? or a mirror?

Answer (score 3):

> untested code:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(bashcommand);
pr.waitFor();
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

while ( ( String line ; line = buf.readLine() ) != null ) 
{
  System.out.println(line);
}
```