# Bash scripting with netbeans/java

Tags: java, bash, netbeans, scripting, putty

Is it possible too call bash script from java ?
and get, set and assign from netbeans 
in the past we scripted with putty.

if true where can I learn more about it ?
Any information would be awesome

Comment: `Is it possible...` ==> -1.  `where can I learn more...` ==> -1.  Have you read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) yet?

Comment: Well you could simply LOOK FOR the answer. There were some here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825001/running-a-bash-command-from-within-a-java-program
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890175/how-do-i-execute-bash-commands-and-collect-the-output-from-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707519/running-a-bash-shell-script-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ProcessBuilder](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html)

(there were many similar questions...)